# Magento2 - Adminhtml - Checkboxes default as checked when it does not show as checked

Tags: adminhtml, uicomponent, magento2.1.11

I am a bit of a lost as to handling checkboxes (a group of them) for a custom form, made as a UI Component.

On the form, they look as if they are unchecked, but if I click them then it reacts normally, but the "Pencil" indicator does not show up on the tab button on the left of the admin page until I unchecked the checkbox that it shows this part of the form has been changed. Furthermore, if I submit the form without changing the checkboxes then the POST data shows they are checked with their correct values. It is only when I "check" then "uncheck" the boxes that the POST value does NOT include the fields.Please reply me if anyone know.

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/location_listing.xml**

```
<fieldset name="features">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Features</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <field name="feature_discovery">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Discovery Center</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="checked" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">features</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="feature_classes">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Classes</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="value" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                <item name="checked" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">features</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="feature_outlet">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Outlet Center</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="value" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                <item name="checked" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">features</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

[image: Before any interaction]

[image: After checking an "unchecked" box]

[image: After unchecked a checked box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went from:

```
<field name="feature_classes">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Classes</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">2</item>
            <item name="checked" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">features</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

To

```
<field name="feature_classes">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Classes</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">features</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Basically replacing the `value` and `checked` items for a `valueMap` item.